# TemplateDoesNotExist at /blog/createposts/ [No template names provided ]

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-templates

I am newbie to django. I do not know how to fix this issue. What I have tried:

1. DIR ['templates']
2. [TEMPLATE_DIR,]
3. TEMPLATE_DIRS = ('os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "templates"),')

   amazonbackend/

   - amazonbackend/

     - settings.py
     - urls.py
     - manage.py
   - Homepage/

     - migrations
     - templates

       - a.html
       - b.html
     - static
   - Blog/

     - migrations
     - templates

       - blog_post.html
       - rich_text_editor_component.html
     - static

**settings.py file**

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'Homepage',
    'blog',
    'crispy_forms',
    'crispy_bootstrap5',
   
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'amazonbackend.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

**views.py file in blog**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse

# Create your views here.

def BlogHomePage(request):
  return render(request, 'Blog_home.html')

def CreatePosts(request):
    return render(request, 'blog_post.html')

def MyPosts(request):
    return render(request,'myposts.html')
```

**rich_text_editor_component.html file in blog**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>Rich Text Editor</title>
<style>
    .rich-text-editor {
        border: 1px solid #ccc;
        background-color: #fff;
    }

    .toolbar {
        background-color: #f0f0f0;
        padding: 5px;
    }

    .editor-content {
        padding: 10px;
    }

    .editor {
        width: 100%;
        min-height: 300px;
        border: 1px solid #ccc;
        padding: 5px;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="rich-text-editor">
    <div class="toolbar">
        <button onclick="execCommand('bold')">Bold</button>
        <button onclick="execCommand('italic')">Italic</button>
        <button onclick="execCommand('underline')">Underline</button>
    </div>
    <div class="editor-content">
        <div class="editor" contenteditable="true"></div>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
    function execCommand(command) {
        document.execCommand(command, false, null);
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

**blog_post.html in blog**

```
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'css/blog_post.css' %}"/>
    <title>Create Posts</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="button-group">
        <button id="preview-button">Preview</button>
        <button id="save-draft-button">Save as Draft</button>
        <button id="publish-button">Publish</button>
    </div>
    <div class="title-bar">
        <input type="text" id="post-title" placeholder="Enter post title">
    </div>
    <div class="rich-toolbar">
        {% include rich_text_editor_component.html %}
    </div>
    <div class="content-container">
        <textarea id="post-content" placeholder="Write your post content here"></textarea>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**Line that causes error:
{% include rich_text_editor_component.html %}** in blog/templates/post_blog.html

Error:

```
TemplateDoesNotExist at /blog/createposts/
No template names provided
```

Answer (score 0):

If you do `{% include rich_text_editor_component.html %}` then I believe it tries to interpret `rich_text_editor_component.html` as a variable.  I think you want `{% include 'rich_text_editor_component.html' %}`

Comment: thankyou Tim Tisdall. problem solved.

Comment: @osamaaslam - I'd appreciate it if you accepted the answer

Comment: @TimTisdall I can understand the addiction ;)

Comment: I am newbie to Django and stackoverflow. I do not know where to find accept button in stackoverflow, but If the casee is to write then "Thankyou, @TimTisdall I accepted your answar"

Comment: @osamaaslam - There are voting buttons to the left of the answer and just below that is a checkmark you can click to accept an answer.